# React-native Drag the edge of the element to change size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to create a screen in my mobile app (built using React-native), there I wanted to provide a feature in which user can drag the edge of the element (say for example, a box) to change its size.

Please check this link to understand requirement.
https://support.wix.com/en/article/resizing-an-element

Not able to find any support or any library / plugin where it is already done for react-native mobile app.

Can someone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

*Note* - Same this is available for React web app. (Link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rnd)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52918071/2520628 and https://medium.com/@audytanudjaja/react-native-ui-challenge-building-instagram-zoom-draggable-photo-9127413b1d29

You should be able to get start ;)

Comment: Thanks Man. It's a great article to approach the solution.